# Static Field with dynamic values on a content app's dialog

Tags: java, jcr, magnolia

i have a custom content app with this basic structure (with alphabetical order):

|-A (folder)
|-|-> aaaa (content app type)
|-|-> ababa (content app type)
|-B (folder)
|-|-> bbbb (content app type)
|-|-> bababa (content app type)

When i select the node "aaaa" (for example) and click on Edit it opens a content app dialog where i can change "aaaa" value. I would like to provide additional information (maybe in a static field) on the "aaaa" (that is linked to another resource in another content app) in the dialog.

How can I display custom info in the dialog? I should change some field's class? How?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to have 2 dialogs, one for content type A, one for content type B.
Then you configure "editA" and "editB" actions for the action bar, one to open dialog A, one to open dialog B. And you set availability on those actions so that first is visible only when selected item is of content type A and similarly second is available only selected item is of content type B.
If you give both edit actions same label, user will not even recognize the difference in workbench until dialog is open.
You can use inheritance to ensure there's no duplication in dialog fields setting, but retain full flexibility.

Obviously, you can also create availability checker based on other criteria, not just the content types.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I solved the problem by extending 3 classes in order to pass the item object through them. I extended: AbstractFieldFactory (in which I replicated the abstract method "createFieldComponent ()" with an identical one passing the "item") and then replicated the StaticFieldDefinition and the StaticFieldFactory so that they called the "createFieldComponent (item)". So I set the right configurations and now retrieve "custom values" in the Static Field. Thank u again!